# loop through nested object properties

Tags: javascript

I am trying to check for an empty value in a nested object, how would I loop through the nested properties?

```
for (var propt in updatedInputs) {

  if (updatedInputs[propt] == "") this.cancelSubmit();

  // check for nested properties
  if (updatedInputs.hasOwnProperty(propt)) {

    // loop through nested properties here

  }
}
```

Sample object:

```
Object {contacts: Array[5]}
    contacts: Array[5]
    0: "04354355"
    1: "24349878779"
    2: "wqewqewqeqw"
    3: "wqewqeqwe"
    4: ""
```

Comment: Please give sample object

Comment: You mean if one of the nested properties were an array or an object?

Comment: That sample object isn't a valid js object, the syntax is wrong. Also, are you trying to loop through a nested array or a nested object?

Comment: Can you please show how `updatedInputs` looks like? Or be more specific on which type (array or object) you are looping on, and, if needed, how many nested levels you need to check.

Comment: This is completely unclear what you are working with. Your broken code showing undefined variables is not a good substitute for a proper explanation and reasonable sample of input data and expected results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fine I think it'll do what you want now.

```
function iterObj(obj) {

  for (var key in obj) {
    console.log(key + ': ' + obj[key]);
    if (obj[key] !== null && typeof obj[key] === "object") {
      // Recurse into children
      iterObj(obj[key]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This will only work if `updateInputs` is an array but the OP says he's looping over an object. There's no such thing as `forEach` on an object.

Comment: If it did, then there would be no point for `$.each()` ^_^